# increase speed in rendering images on power bi from google storage

Tags: powerbi, storage, bucket

I made a dashboard with power bi and I've been using the google storage url to import the pictures, but its taking too much time rendering.
Is there a way to make this faster?
Some faster link to the pictures, or a url that allows me to resize the files.